# Ubuntu Dual Boot windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I installed ubuntu 13.xxxx the latest version for desktop. I did so as a dual boot with uefi and secureboot enabled. Now I can boot into ubuntu just fine. However, I can't boot to windows 8. I have been told boot-repair is the answer to this. That's great. However, I can't boot to disc or usb at the moment. I can't turn secure boot off from the bios. So how would I go about running boot repair like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can install and run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from your working Ubuntu installation; there's no need to boot an emergency disc to use it.