# Can not Boot up laptop after Linux installation

Tags: boot, windows-8, uefi

I have a windows 8 laptop. I went to install fedora 21. I deleted the D drive which had nothing on it. I then installed fedora on that partition. I restarted the computer and it booted into the bios. It had no boot order options or and boot config options. I booted into a live USB with Ubuntu on it and open gparted and I deleted the fedora partition. I rebooted and It went back into the BIOS. I still had no boot options. I then booted up with a live USB with gparted. When I did It would not boot up right. It booted into Emergency Mode. I can't boot into anything. I tried booting into a live fedora USB and I got an error. Its been a while since this so I may have missed some details. I just tried booting into Ubuntu on a USB and it worked. I had my IT teacher look at my laptop but he could not figure it out. He read that you can't have two EFI OS's on the same drive. I don't know exactly what is wrong but I was thinking maybe I need to fix the boot loader. I was thinking I could boot in to a windows 8 disk and repair the boot loader but I don't have a disk.

Can I get windows 8 back and if I can how can I?
How can I install a Linux distro properly?

UPDATE:
In Ubuntu I have access to all my windows files if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! this website serves exclusively for Ubuntu distro, questions on other distributions should be addressed to e.g.: [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: you should specify your OS in order to understand it more clearly because you listed Windows, Fedora, Ubuntu are trying to have them all installed?

Comment: @JoKeR I think this question is not off topic, because it has a good Ubuntu answer, so it should stay here.

Comment: @karel I agree now, I thought he wanted to install Fedora with Windows or something. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Dual Boot windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355019/ubuntu-dual-boot-windows-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot with Ubuntu Live USB. Install Ubuntu somewhere. Boot with Ubuntu, open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now restart your PC. You should see both Windows and Ubuntu options at GRUB boot menu.

That's all the help I can provide with the information you gave, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I am trying that now. It has a lot of different partitions. Would it be safe to delete some of them?

Comment: No need to DELETE them, this would create unallocated spaces. Just format them. Oh, one more thing before you try my answer: when you finished installing Ubuntu, stay in the Live CD, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install grub`. I'm not sure it's pretty necessary, but for security reasons...

Comment: I'm glad it worked! You're always welcome to ask more questions.

Comment: +1 for a giving a good answer to a confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

First, your teacher was wrong in saying you can't have two EFI-based OSes on a single hard disk; there's no problem with such a configuration. In fact, once you understand the rules and the quirks of your particular computer, it's generally easier to install more OSes on an EFI-based computer than on a BIOS-based one. Those two caveats are important, though; most people underestimate the differences between EFI and BIOS and so make mistakes. There are also some pretty substantial EFI bugs that can cause problems on specific computers.

It's hard to know what sort of problem you've got because you haven't presented the sort of detailed information required for diagnosis. Three likely possibilities are a damaged NVRAM boot manager entry, a damaged EFI boot loader, and a completely-destroyed Windows installation. If you need more help, you'll need to post the `RESULTS.txt` file created by [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) -- and if you want to post it here, you should at least attempt an Ubuntu install first, since this is an Ubuntu site. (OTOH, for best safety, you should run Boot Info Script *before doing anything else,* lest you make matters worse. Thus, you may need to take your problem to another site.)

For more general information on installing Ubuntu or other Linux distributions on EFI-based computers, see [my Web page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

One thing you might want to try in the interim is to prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (That page includes download links for images for both media.) If you boot with it, rEFInd should present options to boot any OS with a valid EFI boot loader. If you see a Windows entry, try booting it. If it boots, then your problem is a simple one of a bad NVRAM entry. This can be fixed by Windows utilities, but you'd best ask about that on a Windows site. If rEFInd doesn't show you a Windows entry, then the Windows boot loader has been deleted, renamed, or damaged. The entire Windows installation might or might not have been deleted, too.